# Iterating over a tuple at jit-compile time in numba

Tags: python, numba

Is there a way in a numba jitted function to evaluate every function in a tuple (or list) of functions, at compile time?

Please note that this question is about *how to use a Python loop to construct jit code at compile time*, rather than iterating over a tuple at runtime, which I know is not supported.

A full non-working example is below, but the core of it is that the following works:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def do_stuff(func_tuple):
    results = []
    results.append(func_tuple[0]())
    results.append(func_tuple[1]())
    results.append(func_tuple[2]())
    results.append(func_tuple[3]())
    return results
```

but the following does not:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def do_stuff_2(func_tuple):
    results = []
    for i in range(4):
        results.append(func_tuple[i]())
    return results
```

The error message is as follows, and its meaning is quite clear: indexing into such a tuple is not supported at runtime.

```
Invalid usage of getitem with parameters ((type(CPUDispatcher(<function f1 at 0x116968268>)), type(CPUDispatcher(<function f2 at 0x1169688c8>)), type(CPUDispatcher(<function f3 at 0x1169a1b70>)), type(CPUDispatcher(<function f4 at 0x1169a1f28>))), int64)
 * parameterized
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at numba_minimal_not_working_example_2.py (36)

File "numba_minimal_not_working_example_2.py", line 36:
def do_stuff_2(func_tuple):
    <source elided>
    for i in range(4):
        results.append(func_tuple[i]())
  ^
```

However, I only need the indexing to occur at compile time - I basically just want to generate functions similar to `do_stuff`, but to do so automatically depending on the number of elements in the tuple.

In principle this can happen at compile time, because numba considers the length of a tuple to be part of its type. But I have not been able to work out how to do this. I have tried various tricks involving recursion and/or the `@generated_jit` decorator, but I haven't managed to hit on something that works. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the full example:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f1():
    return 1

@jit(nopython=True)
def f2():
    return 2

@jit(nopython=True)
def f3():
    return 3

@jit(nopython=True)
def f4():
    return 4

func_tuple = (f1, f2, f3, f4)

# this works:
@jit(nopython=True)
def do_stuff(func_tuple):
    results = []
    results.append(func_tuple[0]())
    results.append(func_tuple[1]())
    results.append(func_tuple[2]())
    results.append(func_tuple[3]())
    return results

# but this does not:
@jit(nopython=True)
def do_stuff_2(func_tuple):
    results = []
    for i in range(4):
        results.append(func_tuple[i]())
    return results

# this doesn't either (similar error to do_stuff_2).
@jit(nopython=True)
def do_stuff_3(func_tuple):
    results = [f() for f in func_tuple]
    return results


print(do_stuff(func_tuple)) # prints '[1, 2, 3, 4]'

print(do_stuff_2(func_tuple)) # gives the error above

#print(do_stuff_3(func_tuple)) # gives a similar error
```

Comment: OK, here is a tricky one question. Why would you want to `jit` the function `do_stuff()`? The time required for the functions is likely to be your speed bottleneck anyway...

Comment: @norok2 this is just a minimal example to illustrate the problem. I'm actually generating a rather complicated function which does this many times, and I need the whole thing to be jit-compiled.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known [limitation of Numba](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1446).
This is also mentioned somehow in the traceback you [get](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile).

Basically, when you ask to `@jit` your function, Numba is not able to properly infer types for the compiled code.

One workaround could be to use `@jit(nopython=False)` on `do_stuff_2()`, which would then be able to handle such code by making use of the Python objects system.
Instead, you will not be able to `@jit` the `do_stuff_3()` function, not even with `nopython=False`, since comprehensions are not supported by `numba` (at least up to version 0.39.0).

Comment: I am aware that comprehensions aren't supported, and I understand what the error message means. My point is that I don't actually need to index into the tuple at runtime but only at compile time, which *is* supported, as the `do_stuff()` example demonstrates. I don't think it's a problem of type inference, it's just a problem of how to tell numba to do the loop at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: What makes you think that this is supported by Numba when the authors explicitly tell otherwise? It is not the indexing the problem, it's the loop.

Comment: No loop is needed except at compile time. It only needs to be a Python loop to construct the numba code, not a runtime numba loop. This is all explained in the question already.

Comment: It really looks like a lame behavior, I agree. And there should be a way of compiling this code. The problem is actually not the loop itself. But the fact that as soon as `i` is updated, Numba is unable to guess its type properly at compile time to make sure that `func_tuple` slicing works properly. You can check this out by trying jitting `i = 0; results.append(func_tuple[i]()); i += 1; results.append(func_tuple[i]())`, but replacing `i += 1` with `i = 1` would work.

Comment: I think the problem is deeper than the typing of i. Look at what happens if you replace `func_tuple = (f1, f2, f3, f4)` with `func_tuple = (f1, f1, f1, f1)`. It runs perfectly regardless of the type of i and the presence of the loop!!! Is it worth raising the question again here or as an issue on github?